# Reading a local xml file in Webstorm IDE.(+ node.js, ajax)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js, webstorm

I am now using the latest Webstorm IDE for developing the webpage with Ajax.

**1.**
To read a local xml file, I start the server and access the localhost with chrome but I didn't read a local xml file.

**2.**
To read a local xml file, I use the Webstorm function in following image.

finally, I success the reading a local xml file.

[image]

- What is difference between "number1 method" and "number2 method"?

Thank you in advance!!

==========================================================================

`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#resourceName').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ResourceFormat/xml/test.xml",
                type: "get",
                dataType: "text",
                cache: false,
                timeout: 30000,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#bodyText').val(data);
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + ': ' + xhr);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of Same-origin policy, you can reference to below links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs
- [Can't load a file in ajax from my pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137687/cant-load-a-file-in-ajax-from-my-pc)
- [xmlhttprequest for local files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683596/xmlhttprequest-for-local-files)